# Class context overrides Module methods with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to solve an issue with the Devise gem. The issue is when using standard devise with devise_token_auth.

In application_controller.rb, devise_token_auth requires you to add a module:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
```

After adding this SetUserBytToken module, I load the users/sign_in path in the browser (not the /api/v1/auth/sign_in). The users/sign_in path should load devise, not devise_token_auth.

However, I get an error:

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) def resource_class

`devise_token_auth` invokes this in set_user_by_token.rb:

```
  def set_user_by_token(mapping=nil)
    # determine target authentication class
    rc = resource_class(mapping)
```

There is a method in the same file that looks like this:

```
def resource_class(m=nil)
```

So that method accepts a DEFAULT argument. However, you saw the error, right?

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

So this method must be overwritten some how. Check this out:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/DeviseController%3Aresource_class

Devise has a method with same name that does not take optional argument. I don't understand how that method can be overriding the one defined in SetUserByToken module. Since I call the method in SetUserByToken, shouldn't ruby look at the one defined in the module and not somewhere else? https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb

Comment: Your inheritance hierarchy is unclear to me. However, going by the title of your question: "Class context overrides Module methods with the same name?" Yes, that is how it works. `class C; include M end` makes `M` the superclass of `C`, that's all it does. Since `M` is the superclass of `C` (or looking at it from the other side `C` is a subclass of `M`), methods defined in `C` override methods defined in `M`, that's just how inheritance works. If you want `M`'s methods to override `C`'s, you need to use `prepend` which puts `M` in *front* of the `ancestors` list.

Comment: Yes you answered my question. Nevertheless, I moved to the simple_token_authentication gem isntead of this one. This one is unmaintained and has more issues than what I described above.

Comment: Okay. I'm pretty sure that there is a duplicate question out there, but I can't find it at the moment. Maybe someone else with better search skills can close the question. In the meantime, I'm gonna whip up a quick answer.

Comment: BTW: I never understood why people try to awkwardly explain mixins in Ruby with stuff like "the methods get included into the class" or "including makes the module methods available to the class" or something like that. It's not even a simplification for the benefit of newbies, in fact, it makes it *harder* to understand what's going on! Mixin inheritance is class inheritance, plain and simple. `</rant>` over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Class context overrides Module methods with the same name?

Yes, that is how it works.

```
class C
  include M
end
```

makes `M` the superclass of `C`, that's all it does.

Since `M` is the superclass of `C` (or looking at it from the other side `C` is a subclass of `M`), methods defined in `C` override methods defined in `M`, that's just how inheritance works.

If you want `M`'s methods to override `C`'s, you need to use prepend which puts `M` in front of the `ancestors` list.

---

More precisely, an *include class* `M′` is created whose class variable table pointer, constant table pointer, and method table pointer point to `M`'s class variable table, `M`'s constant table, and `M`'s method table. `M′`'s superclass pointer is set to `C`'s superclass, then `C`'s superclass pointer is set to `M′`. The `Object#class` and `Class#superclass` methods know to "skip" singleton classes and include classes, and `Module#ancestors` knows to return the corresponding module instead of the include class, so you don't *see* this working, but that's what happens.

This explains why methods defined in the class override methods defined in the included module. It also explains the behavior of `super` with modules. It's all just straightforward class inheritance.